# Splitting numpy array at an index

Tags: python, numpy

How do i split a numpy array at an index

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3,3,3))
#What i want to achieve is 3 x (3x3) matrix
```

I would like to convert my (3,3,3) matrix into a list of (3x3) matrix

I could do:

```
b = []
for i in a:
   b.append(i)
```

But there should be a better way

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is: `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` are 3x3.

Comment: I could do a for loop and append each a[0], a[1],a[2] to a list but i wonder if theres a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear you want to convert a *3-dimensional* array into a list containing three *2-dimensional* arrays.

You can directly assign the arrays, to new names (3 of them):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((3,3,3))
b,c,d = a
my_list = [b, c, d]
```

You have the new arrays and the resulting list.

If you do not need the arrays, then you can use the numpy array's `tolist` method:

```
my_list = a.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

`list` can take any iterable so you could just use it:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> array = np.ones((3,3,3))
>>> list_of_arrays = list(array)  # convert it to a list

>>> list_of_arrays
[array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])]
```

However there is (almost) never any reason to convert your numpy array to a list of arrays. There is [slicing and indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) if you only want to access certain elements of the array. There are [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) or [Pandas Dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) if you want table-like arrays. Also it is always possible to use the `axis` parameter for the numpy functions to apply them on your 3x3 matrices in one go:

```
>>> array = np.ones((3,3,3)) * np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1,1)

>>> array.sum(axis=(1,2)) # getting the sum of all the 3x3 matrices
array([  9.,  18.,  27.])
```

Answer (score -1):

A more pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
b = [x for x in a]
```

Comment: any numpyic way? or jsut this will do